# React output JSON on new line

Tags: json, api, reactjs

I am have managed to output the JSON from an API, however it is outputted in one large block, I however wish to display each piece of json on a new line everytime there is a closing '}'.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import $ from 'jquery';

class App extends Component {

  state = {result : null}

  componentDidMount = () => {

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'http://localhost:3001/data',
      data: {},
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
      },
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: (result) => {
        this.setState({result : result});
      }
    });

  };

  render() {
    return (
          <div className="App">
            <header>
              <h2>Last Application Deployment </h2>
            </header>
            <div id='renderhere'>
              {JSON.stringify(this.state.result)}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
  }
    }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First option: if you want to output JSON for debugging purpose, you should try [react-json-pretty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-pretty)

Second option: if what you trying to do is supposed to be for production do something like this:

```
<div id='renderhere'>
  <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.result, null, 2)}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I am already using `JSON.stringify()`, what I am trying to achieve is, instead of outputting the JSON as a whole block, I want each object in the JSON to be outputted to the browser on a new line, sorry if this wasnt clear.

Comment: Sorry, my code example was broken, please check the answer again.

Comment: **That is great!** Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try to wrap your text around this css style. and your issue will be solved. No complicated functions needed for this.

```
 <p style={{whiteSpace: 'pre-line'}}>my json text goes here \n\n</p>
```